# Modify a list's elements based on element index

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell, indexing

Using Haskell:

Let's say I have list: `[1,3,4,2,3]`
And I want to modify all 3's in the list. I know that I can apply this to select the 3's in this case:

```
map (\x -> if p x then f x else x) xs
```

However, the functions being applied to the threes is dependent on their index within the list.

So for example if the index was added to the desired number the output of the function I'm going for would be: `[1,4,4,2,7]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) for this:

```
zipWith (\i x -> if p x then f i x else x) [0..] xs
```

where `f` thus takes `i` (the index) and `x` (the element) both into account.

For example:

```
zipWith (\i x -> if x == 3 then (i+x) else x) [0..] xs
```

Which generates the desired output:

```
Prelude> let xs = [1,3,4,2,3]
Prelude> zipWith (\i x -> if x == 3 then (i+x) else x) [0..] xs
[1,4,4,2,7]
```

You can encapsulate this logic into a separate function, for instance `imap :: (Enum n, Num n) => (n -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b`:

```
imap :: (Enum n, Num n) => (n -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b
imap = flip zipWith [0..]
```

This will work with any type that is an instance of `Num` and `Enum` (so `Integer`, `Int`, `Float`,...).

Answer (score 1):

While `zipWith` is probably the right way, just for a variety you may go recursive as follows;

```
tpi :: [Int] -> [Int]
tpi = runner 0
      where runner _ []     = []
            runner n (x:xs) | x == 3    = (n + x) : runner (n+1) xs
                            | otherwise = x : runner (n+1) xs
```